# Problems with Delphi 2009 + HidD_GetSerialNumberString

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, hid

I am having problems getting HidD_GetSerialNumberString to simply give me the serialnumber of *some* devices.
On some devices it works fine, but on others all I get is "ÿÿÿ" as the serialnumber.
I am suspecting it has something to do with Delphi 2009 and it's unicode, but I simply cannot get my head around it.
Is there a solution to this?

Edit (declaration) :

```
type
THidD_GetSerialNumberString = function(HidDeviceObject: THandle; Buffer: PWideChar; BufferLength: Integer): LongBool; stdcall;

var
HidD_GetSerialNumberString: THidD_GetSerialNumberString;

//in the LoadHid-function
@HidD_GetSerialNumberString := GetModuleSymbolEx(HidLib, 'HidD_GetSerialNumberString', Result);
```

Usage :

```
var
  test : PWideChar;
...

GetMem(test, 512);
if HidD_GetSerialNumberString(HidFileHandle, Test, 512) then
  FSerialNumber := test; //FSerialNumber is WideString
FreeMem(test);
```

Comment: Please show code, in particular the declaration of, and call to `HidD_GetSerialNumberString`

Comment: I am using the JVCL's jvHidControllerClass.pas and Hid.pas

Comment: That's nice. Please show the code that I asked for.

Comment: what is GetModuleSymboleEx?

Comment: did you try to zero the buffer before calling the api?

Comment: @remko http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JCL_Help:GetModuleSymbolEx

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine in all versions of Delphi. Although clearly it involves a UTF-16 to ANSI conversion when compiled by a pre-Unicode Delphi. However, since you use Delphi 2009 that is not an issue.

There are no problems regarding Unicode conversions. The `HidD_GetSerialNumberString` function fills out the buffer that you supply with a null-terminated UTF-16 string. And since you declared `test` to be exactly that, Delphi will generate code necessary to copy to a Delphi `string` variable.

Is it possible that `HidD_GetSerialNumberString` is returning false and so `FSerialNumber` is not initialized properly? Other than that, the only conclusions that one can make are that:

- `HidD_GetSerialNumberString` is lying to you when it returns `True`.
- The serial number returned by calling `HidD_GetSerialNumberString` really is `ÿÿÿ`.

Comment: I don't understand that comment. Do you mean that the answer to my final sentence is no? Do you mean that `HidD_GetSerialNumberString` always returns `True` or that `FSerialNumber` is always initialized.

Comment: Oh, yes, I meant my code is actually checking for true/false result, but I simplified the code here to make it easier to read.

Comment: Anyway, if your call to `HidD_GetSerialNumberString` returns `True`, then the device's serial number really is what your code says it is, at least according to `HidD_GetSerialNumberString`. In other words, if there is an error, it's not in the code in the question

Comment: That was what I was afraid of. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you looking for more help on this?

Comment: It would be lovely if someone had some knowledge to share on this, yes.

Comment: Ask yourself how we could provide more. Your code is clearly correct. Your expectations from us seem somewhat high.

Comment: Well, StackExchange has proven, time and time again, that some *really* bright minds are present. I am simply hoping for someone to come along and recognize this particular situation, and share some insight.

Comment: ...also, though my code may be correct, I might do something else wrong or neglect to do something that is necessary for this to work porperly...

Comment: Well, I'm very sorry that I've not been able to help you and provide that insight. It would seem that you need to ask another different question asking specifically for that.